# No option to create new partition- why?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hard-drive, diskmanagement

Why can't I create a new partition as per below?
This is the disk of a physical server running Hyper-V 2012.

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 Terabyte limit on MBR disks.  Convert the disk to GPT for > 2TB.

**Edit:** For completeness - Back up all your data first. Wipe out all the partitions and volumes on the disk. Then right-click on the disk itself on the left hand side and choose "Convert to GPT."

Comment: +1, but this answer would be even better if it also said how to do it.